# SQL Pivot table with data across annual results

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to get a simple pivot table to analyse turnover against expenses across multiple years.  My source data table is simple as is this:

```
GroupName|Total|Year|

Income   |1000 |2012|    
Income   |1200 |2013|    
Income   |1500 |2014|    
Expenses |750  |2012|    
Expenses |800  |2013|    
Expenses |950  |2014|
```

I'm looking to get this to pivot to:

```
GroupName|2012|2013|2014|

Income   |1000|1200|1500|
Expenses |750 |800 |950 |
```

Pretty simple I guess if you know how but I'm still trying to understand pivots in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT GroupName, [2012], [2013], [2014]
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM MyTable) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
( 
   AVG(Total)
   FOR Year IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])
) AS PivotTable
```

you get the desired output:

```
GroupName   2012    2013    2014
---------------------------------
Expenses    750     800     950
Income      1000    1200    1500
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be useful :

```
SELECT GroupName,
       [2012],
       [2013],
       [2014]
FROM   Tabl
       PIVOT ( Max(Total)
             FOR Yr IN ([2012],
                        [2013],
                        [2014]) ) AS PivotTable
```

NOTE : if there are two of more rows  with same `GroupName` and `Yr`  then it will pick the total which is maximum among them and will show it in output.

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1b3b/4)